# About the `Elasticsearch.index()` method, is it using PUT or POST?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

We are looking into a Python library [`Elasticsearch Python Client`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py), and its official online document contains the below example for ingesting data into Elastic.

We hope to make the ingest action idempotent, so we wonder whether the library's `index()` method uses `PUT` or `POST`.

[This reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) says:

> **The PUT Method**
> The difference between POST and PUT is that PUT requests are idempotent. ...

**The example in the official online document:**

```py
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('https://localhost:9200')

doc = {
    'author': 'author_name',
    'text': 'Interensting content...',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
resp = es.index(index="test-index", id=1, document=doc)
print(resp['result'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [elasticsearch-py v8.8.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/v8.8.0/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py#L2212), the code for the `index` method contains:

```py
def index(
    ...
) -> ObjectApiResponse[t.Any]:
    """
    Creates or updates a document in an index.
    ...
    """
    ...
    if index not in SKIP_IN_PATH and id not in SKIP_IN_PATH:
        __path = f"/{_quote(index)}/_doc/{_quote(id)}"
        __method = "PUT"
    elif index not in SKIP_IN_PATH:
        __path = f"/{_quote(index)}/_doc"
        __method = "POST"
    ...
    return self.perform_request(  # type: ignore[return-value]
        __method, __path, params=__query, headers=__headers, body=__body
    )
```

which seems to indicate that:

- If an `id` is specified, it's a PUT
- If an `id` is *not* specified, then it's a `POST` ([and a document ID is auto-generated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/docs-index_.html#create-document-ids-automatically)).

That's for the sync version of the `Elasticsearch` client. The same code appears on the async version of the client `AsyncElasticsearch`:  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/v8.8.0/elasticsearch/_async/client/__init__.py#L2214

As to the difference in behavior of the PUT and POST on Elasticsearch, rather than a generic reference on PUT and POST, it is best to consult Elasticsearch's Index API documentation itself: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/docs-index_.html.